# Disable multiple username hints without disabling "Remember Username"?

Tags: security, single-sign-on, user, login-errors

In the current release, Salesforce released the [multiple username hint](http://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/multiple-username-login-hints/) "enhancement". This causes two showstopper issues:

- if a username has an apostrophe in it, the "pick a username" screen where you select a username does not work at all when you click your username (Javascript escaping bug).
- if the org has SSO enabled, clicking a username always redirects to the SAML front door URL, even though in this case SSO is only used by a tiny subset of users.

The multiple username hint feature itself is of no use to this customer since almost 100% of their users only have one SFDC account. However, to disable it, you have to disable the "Enable caching and autocomplete on login page" setting in Session Settings. This has the (also very undesirable) effect of making the "Remember User Name" checkbox no longer have an effect.

Ideally, we'd like to disable the "multiple username hint" feature, while preserving the old functionality of "Remember User Name" pre-populating a single username in the login form.

Alternatively, is there a way to prevent the pre-populated username selection from ever going to the SAML front door page? That would be acceptable as well (other than for the few people who have apostrophes in their names).

We have filed cases for these issues, but in lieu of a speedy bugfix, would be very interested in any potential workarounds. It may seem like a minor thing, but not being able to remember user names at all is causing significant user distress.

EDIT: according to SFDC, these are both known issues. I couldn't find a listed known issue for the apostrophe issue, but the SAML redirect issue appears to be related to [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3tAAAS) which affects organisations with an enabled My Domain. The fix (at least for now) appears to be requesting a deletion of the custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile as a workaround, please try clearing the browser cache and you should not have the issue.(But you will have to inform all the users)

Or contact salesforce support, so they can remove the domain name where in that case you will be loosing your domain name and SSO users will not be able to login.

Comment: Telling thousands of users to clear their browser cache every time they sign out isn't a feasible solution, although it is technically a workaround (as mentioned in the SFDC article I linked to). For now, it does appear that requesting the deletion of the custom domain is the fix, at least until Spring '14 Patch 19 comes out (hopefully soon).